# Disable or override Power button onClick method

Tags: android, button, screen

I'm working on application which shouldn't allow action like switching off screen which is performed by clicking power button. There could be long click action on this button still working. Anyone know how to disable switch off screen in application setting flag KEEP_SCREEN_ON didn't block it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt you will be allowed to do that, as in this sort of functionality will most likely deliberatley not have been added to sdk's. Google will insist on basic Anroid system functionality to behave the way Google want it to behave. They have to protect their reputation from abuse and what you are trying to do is clearly abuse of the Operating System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think you can capture the event of clicking on the power button.

the events of the screen occur after they have occurred.

you might be able to capture the power button if the device is rooted (or if the app is a system app), but i'm not sure how.

the only thing that is close to what you want (that i know) is to listen to the event of screen being turned off, and then cause the screen to be turned on ,which (according to what i remember, might be wrong on this) requires the permission "DEVICE_POWER" .

Comment: well you wanted to make the screen stay , no?

Comment: stay on not switching on when it was switched off

Comment: i know. i wrote that this is the only close thing i can think of. it's really not the same.